# Change Data bound WPF Datagrid row background/foreground color depending on the boolean property of an object

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I have a Datagrid in WPF application (Using MVVM {Caliburn Micro}) which is bounded to property of type `ObservableCollection<Student>` where Student class looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }
    public bool Passed { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the fact - student passed the exam or not  - I want to change the Background/Foreground of the row of the corresponding student to red (if didn't passed).

Below is shown my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
              RowBackground="White"
              Visibility="Visible"
              Grid.Row="15"
              ColumnWidth="auto"
              IsReadOnly="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource GridBorder}"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
              Name="Students"
              CanUserAddRows="True"  
              BorderThickness="0.8"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action GetRow($dataContext)]"
              SelectionMode="Single" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
```

these are the column Definitions:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="PersonalNumber"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName}" Header="FullName"/>
```

To solve this, I tried something like this, but doesn't work:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Passed}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Passed}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataGrid is setting `RowBackground="White"` which is overriding the RowStyle, remove that setting and the Style will behave as you're expecting it to.

Comment: Thank you, I have not thought about it.. :)