# WPF datagrid change row color based on a property value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid that is filled with a CollectionViewSource and what I want is to change the row background color depending on a binded property value.

- Red if value is "KO"
- Green if value is "OK"
- Yellow if value is "Created"

I've read different threads here on SO such as [Change Data bound WPF Datagrid row background/foreground color depending on the boolean property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694180/change-data-bound-wpf-datagrid-row-background-foreground-color-depending-on-the) or [WPF Datagrid row colour based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016699/wpf-datagrid-row-colour-based-on-value) but still struggling to make this work.

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Here is what I tried:

**Main.Xaml**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <Viewmodel:LoadServerViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid Margin="10,20,20,20" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsReadOnly="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="Created">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="OK">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="KO">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Update" Binding="{Binding LastUp} />
            ....
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
                Content="Refresh"
                Margin="0,0,40,0"
                Height="25"
                Width="90"
                Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                Background="#2f3640"
                Command="{Binding ButtonRefresh}">
</Button>
```

**LoadServerViewModel.cs**

```
private string _rowStatus = "Created";
private readonly RelayCommand _buttonRefresh;

public string RowStatus
{
    get => _rowStatus;
    set
    {
        _rowStatus = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RowStatus));
    }
}

public ICollectionView Servers
{
    get
    {
        if (_collectionViewSource.View != null)
        {
            _collectionViewSource.View.CurrentChanged += (sender, e) => ServerGridFormat = _collectionViewSource.View.CurrentItem as ServerGridFormat;
            return _collectionViewSource?.View;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public ServerGridFormat ServerGridFormat 
{
    get => _servergridformat;
    set
    {
        servergridformat = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ServerGridFormat));
    }
}

public LoadServerViewModel() {
    // Button to trigger the change of RowStatus from "Created" to "OK" therefore the color of all rows
    _buttonRefresh = new RelayCommand(o => RowStatus = "OK");
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are binding to the wrong DataContext. The DataContext of each row is the data item itself (the element of Servers). You must use the DataGrid.DataContext as source. Your current code will change the colors of all rows (just in case your goal was to toggle individual row colors).

Comment: My goal is actually to change the color of each row depending on the RowStatus value but even here, my code doesnt work and do not change any row colors.. can't figure out why..

Comment: Have you fixed your data bindings? If so, can you show them please (update your question).

Comment: Sorry not sure to understand what you mean by changing the DataContext (do you mean ItemsSource?)

Comment: Let's say I'd like to change the colors of all rows, why my current code is not working?

Comment: @EASameh: What's the source of the `ICollectionView`? Each server should have a `RowStatus` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current binding uses the `DataContext` of the individual row as binding source (which is the data model stored in the `ItemsSource`). But your property `RowStatus` is defined on the object that is the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` (which is the `LoadServerViewModel`).

To make it work, you must adjust your data bindings to use the correct source (or alternatively move the `RowSatus` property to the data models):

```xml
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.RowStatus}" 
                 Value="Created">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```